# Queue calls to an async method

Tags: c#, queue, async-await

I have an async operation named Refresh. If a second call to refresh is made before the first is finished I need to queue it. This is what I have:

```
public async Task Refresh(RefreshArgs refreshArgs)
{
    await EnqueueRefreshTask(refreshArgs);
}

private Queue<RefreshArgs> refreshQueue =
    new Queue<RefreshArgs>();

private async Task EnqueueRefreshTask(RefreshArgs refreshArgs)
{
    refreshQueue.Enqueue(refreshArgs);

    await ProcessRefreshQueue();
}

private Task currentRefreshTask = null;

private async Task ProcessRefreshQueue()
{
    if ((currentRefreshTask == null) || (currentRefreshTask.IsCompleted))
    {
        if (refreshQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            var refreshArgs = refreshQueue.Dequeue();

            currentRefreshTask = DoRefresh(refreshArgs);
            await currentRefreshTask;

            await ProcessRefreshQueue();
        }           
    }
}

private async Task DoRefresh(RefreshArgs refreshArgs)
{
    // Lots of code here, including calls to a server that are executed with await.
    // Code outside my control may make another Refresh(args) call while this one is still processing.
    // I need this one to finish before processing the next.
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure it's the best way to do this with Tasks. Any thoughts?

**Update:**

I tried using ActionBlock:

```
public async Task Refresh(RefreshArgs refreshArgs)
{
    if (refreshActionBlock == null)
    {
        var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
        executionDataflowBlockOptions.MaxMessagesPerTask = 1;
        executionDataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        refreshActionBlock = new ActionBlock<RefreshArgs>(args => DoRefresh(args), executionDataflowBlockOptions);
    }

    await refreshActionBlock.SendAsync(refreshArgs);
}
```

This queues DoRefresh, and allows it to run in the UI thread (which I need). Problem is SendAsync doesn't await on the work of DoRefresh.

SendAsync: "Asynchronously offers a message to the target message block, allowing for postponement". I'm only awaiting on the send, not the action its-self.

Doing this doesn't work as expected:

```
await Refresh(RefreshArgs.Something);
// other code goes here. It expects the first refresh to be finished.
await Refresh(RefreshArgs.SomethingElse);
// other code goes here. It expects the second refresh to be finished.
```

The ActionBlock will queue the second refresh, but the awaits fall through before the refresh is done. I need them to return when the work of DoRefresh is done.

Comment: You could replace all of this with an [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx).

Comment: `ActionBlock` is what sprung to my mind. When dealing with sequences of async stuff, TPL DataFlow (of which ActionBlock is a part) is a good approach.

Comment: I think this belongs more in the codereview site.

Comment: Note that `Queue` isn't thread safe; you should be using `BlockingCollection` instead.

Comment: There is also ConcurrentQueue - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Comment: @Servy I think that doesn't actually matter here, since all the code seems to execute on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is to use an `AsyncLock`. You can get one [from Stephen Cleary's library AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock&referringTitle=Documentation), or you can read [Stephen Toub's article about how to build it yourself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx).

When you have `AsyncLock`, implementing your `Refresh()` is straightforward:

```
public async Task Refresh(RefreshArgs refreshArgs)
{
    using (await m_lock.LockAsync())
    {
        // do your async work here
    }
}
```

This will make sure the `Refresh()`es execute one after the other (and not interleaved) and also that the `Task` returned from `Refresh()` completes only after the `Refresh()` is actually done.

You *could* use `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow to do the same, but you would also need to use `TaskCompletionSource` and it would be much more complicated than the `AsyncLock` version.

Answer (score 2):

you can take a look at these posts, they talk about asynchronous coordination (semaphores, reset events) and exclusion using **tasks**:

- [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 1:
  AsyncManualResetEvent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx)
- [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 2:
  AsyncAutoResetEvent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266923.aspx)
- [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 4: AsyncBarrier](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266932.aspx)
- [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 5: AsyncSemaphore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx)

[**Edit**: add part 6]

- [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 6: AsyncLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx)

Comment: You stopped just before the primitive that would be most useful here: `AsyncLock`. Stephen Toub talks about that in [Part 6 of his series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy :)
Only u have need to use " switch - case " !!
now Let's go to show u how to do with small sample code .
sample scenario : we want to download 2 pic , one after another as a queue.

namespace Test
{

```
public partial class SampleOfQueue : Form
{

    public SampleOfQueue() { InitializeComponent(); }
    DBContext db = new DBContext();
    int Queue;

    private void btnStartApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Queue = 0;
        DownloadQueue();
    }

    private void DownloadQueue()
    {
        switch (Queue)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    DownloadFile("http://images.forbes.com/media/lists/53/2009/tom-cruise.jpg", "Tom Cruise 1", "");
                    Queue += 1; break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    DownloadFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Tom_Cruise_Collateral.jpg", "Tom Cruise 2", "");
                    Queue += 1; break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    // Other....
                    Queue += 1; break;
                }
            default: break;
        }

    }

    public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string ImageName, string ImageFarsiName)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

        Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri(urlAddress);
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, "d:\\x.jpg");

    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadQueue();
        if (Queue == 3) { MessageBox.Show("finish"); }
    }

}
```

}

Tested with C# 4.6 in VS 2015 windows form.
Innovative method of myself :)
I hope to be useful <3
Good luck.